# Multiplying imagionary roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I am trying to answer the following question:

> The roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2-16x+25$ are $2+mi$ and $2-mi$, where $m>0$.  Compute the sum of $a+m$.

Should the zeros of the equation be $x-(2+mi)$ and $x-(2-mi)$ or $x-2+mi$ and $x-2-mi$, or maybe something else?  I really have no idea.

Comment: It looks like something went wrong... By factoring you get that $ax^2 - 16x = x(ax-16) = 0$, so we have $x = 0$ of $x = \frac{16}{a}$ are the roots.

Comment: @andybenji it looks like someone who edited the problem made a mistake.  I fixed it.  Can you take another look?

Comment: Yeah definitely.

Comment: @andybenji ...and perhaps answer the question as well???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roots are given by the quadratic formula:
$$x = \frac{16\pm \sqrt{16^2 - 4*25*a}}{2a}$$

We know that the real part of the roots will be $2$, so $\frac{16}{2a} = 2$, and $a = 4$.  So we can plug that back into the quadratic formula.
$$x = \frac{16\pm \sqrt{16^2 - 4*25*4}}{2*4}$$
and solve for your roots.

That should be more than enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the roots back into the original problem for x. One at a time. You will end with a system of equations with two unknowns. Then you can solve for a and m.